# How is the ability of a single charger to charge a range of types of mobile phones achieved?

Tags: power-supply, power

Chargers that are supplied with eg an Android phone can be plugged into some other non-Android type phones and charge them successfully.

How is this inter-brand and inter-system charging possible?

A typical connector used in such systems looks like this -

[image]

---

Note: The link to the connector image was in the original post but did not show - presumably due to the OP's rep level - RM

Comment: There is a modern charging standard that has been adopted by most mobile phone manufacturers and also by makers of other small portable products with Lithium Ion single cell (3.6V nominal) batteries such as cameras, MP3 platers etc. Products which comply with the standard can often use the same chargers. It does not matter if they are Android based or some other system as long as they use the same charging standard. The standard uses a micro USB connector (NOT mini-USB) and applies 5V to the power leads of the USB connection. ....

Comment: .... There are some other factors relating to being able to determine how much current a power supply can provide but for practical purposes they are essentially a 5V power supply with an agreed connector. A charger that is suitable for a high capacity battery system will usually work with a lower capacity phone (as voltage is really all that matters) but a charger for a low capacity phone may not be able to charge a high capacity phone due to being loaded down too much by the higher load. Manufacturers could overcome this limitation if they wished to but may not choose to.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are missing is that the external "charger" is **not** a charger at all; it's just a DC power supply, providing 5V at some maximum current, typically 1A or 2.1A.

The actual charger is circuitry built into the phone itself. It takes the incoming 5VDC and controls the voltage/current going into the battery. Because it is part of the phone itself, it is already programmed with the characteristics of the battery. (In some cases with removable batteries, the battery characteristics are stored inside the battery pack, probably in a small microcontroller, which communicates with the main charger.)

There is another factor, which is the external power supply indicating to the phone how much current can be drawn. This is different between Apple devices and Android devices and may involve fixed resistors on the USB data lines or a small microcontroller inside the power supply brick.

Answer (score 1):

A USB charger (any USB charger) is supposed to supply 5VDC. Most of these phones, iPhone being a notable exception, have micro USB connectors. USB is a standard. Since the chargers and mobile phones comply with this standard one can plug any compliant charger into any compliant device without fear of damaging the device. Now, having said that, we come to the subject of current, here the standards compliance gets more than a little fuzzy. The USB standard says 500mA at 5V but for many modern devices you will find that it takes too long to charge the device (many devices will discharge the batteries faster than you can charge them). So most chargers can supply much more (as much as 2500mA is not uncommon) at 5V. If we stop and think about voltage drop on the wire things get fuzzy indeed. What this all boiles down to is this, there is a standard that all these things comply with; furthermore, the compliant devices are tolerant of fairly large deviations from that standard. If you have a device that requires say 5V at 500mA it is generally safe to use a charger that supplies 5V at 1000mA or 5V at 1500mA etc. In general (e.g. not USB) if you try a charger of a different voltage you will have problems, but so long as the charger can supply at least as much current as the device requires your generally okay but these are rules of thumb not absolutes.